# Is it possible to replace and append a value in an array after using numpy shuffle function?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to make a simple program that shuffles the value of an array then after that replace a value in an index and also append a value at the same time but both replace and append function isn't supported by numpy

here's what I've come up :

```
predCS = pred_CS[0]
actual = new_Ydata_CS
prediction = np.array(["Software Engineer / Programmer", "Technical Support Specialist", "Academician", "Administrative Assistant"])
np.random.shuffle(prediction)
prediction = [prediction.replace(predCS, '0')for prediction in prediction]
prediction.append(predCS)
```

I couldn't find any other way how to replace and append some value after shuffling, is there any alternative way aside from using numpy shuffle?
Any response is highly appreciated :>

Comment: Why arrays?  Why not lists?

Comment: Pickled data is stored in an array that's way i use an array instead of list and i didn't even think about list

Comment: I want to stick on using array as much as possible

Comment: Actualy, after the shuffle, the rest is lists.  The reuse of `prediction` as iteration variable in the list comprehension is confusing to readers.